# Equivalence relation of a group acting on a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations

> Let A be a set and G be any subgroup of S(A). G is a group of permutations of A. Assume that G is a finite group. If u∈A, the orbit of u is the set O(u)={g(u): g∈G}. Define a relation ~ on A by u~v iff g(u)=v for some g∈G. Prove that ~ is an equivalence relation on A, and that the orbits are its equivalence classes.

For some reason I am having a hard time proving the relation. For the symmetric part of the problem I have g(u)=v and that u=g^-1v. From that can I conclude that it implies g(v)=u?

If I can figure out the symmetric part I think I would be able to prove transitivity fairly easy.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Intriguingly, the group axioms (neutral element, inverse element, associativity) are in one-to-one-correspondence with the axioms of equivalence relation (reflexive, symmetric, transitive)

Comment: So would that mean g^-1(v) is equivalent to g(v)?

Comment: @Student No. I think you basically have the symmetric part proven, but you are getting confused by the fact that the definition mentions "some $g \in G$".  This does not mean it has to be the same $g$ every time you use the definition; it just has to be some element of $G$.  It might be clearer if you reword the definition as follows: $u$~$v$ if some element of $G$ sends $u$ to $v$.

Comment: Oh okay. So if the g^-1(v)=u and since G is group than there is some element in G say g1 that is the inverse of g^-1 such that g1(v)=u?