# Prove that "is in the same G-orbit as" is an equivalence relation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group of invertible functions on the set X. Then the set of all G-orbits on X is a partition of the set X, ie. every element of X is one and only one G-orbit. Hence, the relation "is in the same G-orbit as" is an equivalence relation.

I know that I need to prove that it is symmetric, reflexive and transitive. I also know that G-orbits are isometric, which means they are invertible. I am not quite sure where to start.

Comment: If $G$ is all automorphisms of $X$, then there is only one $G$ orbit. Are you sure this is what you're asked to show?

Comment: I just edited the question exactly as I was presented it.

Comment: Does it help to consider the relation "y is a $G$-successor of $x$" defined as "there exists $g$ such that $y = gx$"? You can show this is the same relation as "in the same $G$-orbit as", but may be easier to think about.

Comment: @ziggurism: The premise is surely intended to be read as $G \subseteq \operatorname{Aut}(X)$.

Comment: We have never seen that notation before though, thats what is throwing me off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalence relation of a group acting on a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580292/equivalence-relation-of-a-group-acting-on-a-set)

Comment: Other way around, @Buraian.  The post you link is no closed as a dupe of this post.  There are likely others, too.  But duplicate targets, (one chosen to say other questions are dupes of it), is not necessarily chronological.  More often than not, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you need to show that the relation
$$x\sim y\;\;\;\iff\;\;\;x\in g.y\mbox{ for some }g\in G$$
is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. I do not, however, understand what you mean by "I also know that G-orbits are isometric, which means they are invertible."

Anyway, the relation is reflexive because $x=1.x$.

It is symmetric because, if $x=g.y$, then $g^{-1}.x=g^{-1}.(g.y)=(g^{-1}g).y=1.y=y.$

It is transitive because, if $x=g.y$ and $y=h.z$, then $x=g.y=g.(h.z)=(gh).z$.

Hence, it is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $O: X \to \text{the set of orbits}$ given by $x \mapsto \text{the orbit of } x$.

Then $x \sim y$ iff $O(x) = O(y)$. This is the only point that needs verification. (*)

Since equality is an equivalence relation, so is $\sim$ .

(*) $y \in O(x) \implies y=gx \implies x=g^{-1}y \implies hx = hg^{-1}y \in O(y)$. So $O(x)\subseteq O(y)$. Analogously, $O(y)\subseteq O(x)$.